# Access azure website usage data inside of the ASP.NET app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have a need to monitor the azure Web App's resource usage in relation to the number of users logged into the application.

What is the best way to get information about the running azure environment (processor and memory) usage of the Azure WebApp for an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to setup [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/) in your application. Once done you should be able to get telemetry data with their API
 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931943.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)